# Quicksand - items disappear after sorting

Tags: javascript, quicksand

I want to use the Quicksand sorting plugin for my project.

[My example is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/690vbdfr/)

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.sorted = function(customOptions) {
        var options = {
            reversed: false,
            by: function(a) { return a.text(); }
        };
        $.extend(options, customOptions);
        $data = $(this);
        arr = $data.get();
        arr.sort(function(a, b) {
            var valA = options.by($(a));
            var valB = options.by($(b));
            console.log(valB);
            if (options.reversed) {
                return (valA < valB) ? 1 : (valA > valB) ? -1 : 0;        
            } else {    
                return (valA < valB) ? -1 : (valA > valB) ? 1 : 0;  
            }
        });
        console.log($(arr));
        return $(arr);
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
    var $holder = $('#itemsBox');
    var $data = $holder.clone();
    $('div.preContent a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('div.preContent a').removeClass('active');
        if ($(this).attr('data-sorttype') == 'price'){
            var $filteredData = $data.find('div.item');
            var $sortedData = $filteredData.sorted({
                by: function(v) {
                    return parseFloat($(v).attr('data-price'));
                }
            });
        }
        $holder.quicksand($sortedData, {
            duration: 800,
            easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
        });
    });
});
```

After clicking the link "By price", all the items disappear. Why does this happen?

Comment: Sorry, I just saw _Quicksand - items disappear ..._ and started laughing. +1 for that. :)